# How can I create News Android application without having my own server?

Tags: android

I have tried to create a news app that display news from some website.
Some friends helped me to write some php so that I can call the php using http request and get the JSON from the response.
Then, I can parse the JSON and display the news correctly.
However, the server is not mine.
Actually, I don't want to have server communication using php.
I want to do it just on client side.
1) I know how to parse the html and get the result using python in local machine, is there any way to implement my python code in Android, and after running the python code, it will connect to the news website and display it correctly.
2) If not, what can I do because I do not want to host a server.

Comment: You can do the same parse in Java(android).

Comment: is there any good website I can follow??

Comment: http://www.json.org/ Look under Java. They have 15+ Java libs listed to work with json.

Comment: http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/ will work. But the logic is the same in Java as Python

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly vague question however I will answer the one specific part:

> is there any way to implement my python code in Android, and after running the python code

Yes, its called [Scripting Layer 4 Android](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/) which supports many languages. Specifically I found [python-for-android](http://code.google.com/p/python-for-android/) which allows you to run python on Android devices, which you could use for your application to pull and parse html from a news website.

Comment: @jjLin Do you have a question about the link I provided?

Comment: @jjLin I'm not sure the exact performance, but it's certainly not going to be as fast as a Java app or a native app on Android.